# Сервер теста програмного кода

Tags: php, оптимизация, online

Добрый вечер! Есть ли такой сервер онлайн, где можно было испытывать фрагменты программного кода, где показывало время работы и нагрузку? У меня на данный момент два сервера. Один локалхост, второй платный хост. Не тот не другой точную информацию о  времени выполнения скрипта не дает, т.е не то что точную, скорее разную. Например, один и тот же код может грузить как 0,1 как 0,3 так и 0,007. Насчет найти среднее арифметическое - тоже не вариант. Если запустить тот же скрипт через некоторое время, может быть совсем другой результат. После попробовал через цикл (многое повторение одно и того действия). Но все равно не точность была до секунды. Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервисов таких не знаю, увы. Но разве можно на них положиться, более, чем на собственные машины? Зависит же и от конфига и от сборки php, да много, от чего.
`microtime()` в начале и в конце точно не годится?
Есть ещё всякие дополнения-расширения для профайлинга: [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), [PECL APD](http://www.php.net/apd)

Ну. и не запускайте фотошоп, пока идёт измерение скорости работы скрипта : )

Comment: Кончено на хостинге точнее более (т.е разница не большая) Но всеравно не плохо бы такой проект, какой точно показывал. Спасибо за ответ